# Linked container IP not in hosts

Tags: docker, boot2docker, linux-containers

I'm trying to configure a simple LAMP app.

Here is my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM ubuntu
# ...
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -yq install apache2
# ...
WORKDIR /data
```

And my `docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
db:
    image: mysql
web:
    build: .
    ports:
        - 80:80
    volumes:
        - .:/data
    links:
        - db
    command: /data/run.sh
```

After `docker-compose build` & `up` I was expecting to find `db` added to my `/etc/hosts` (into the `web` container), but it's not there.

How can this be explained ? What am I doing wrong ?

---

Note1: At `up` time, I see only `Attaching to myapp_web_1`, shouldn't I see also `myapp_db_1` ?
Note2: I'm using `boot2docker`

Comment: Does the db container get started at all? Is it in `docker ps`?

Comment: db container not started

Comment: What does `docker-compose logs db` say after `up`?

Comment: I just restarted the whole thing and I noticed the error `Cannot link to a non running container: /bioauth_db_1` at first `up`. `logs db` tells me `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD not set` so maybe that's the issue. Weird I don't see this log at `up` time.

Comment: Yeah, the reason you don't see it is probably that it takes a little time for compose to attach to the containers and the message was  printed in that delay.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. Thanks to you both

Answer (score 0):

Following @Alexandru_Rosianu's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31435423?noredirect=1#comment50845383_31435423), I checked

```
$ docker-compose logs db

error: database is uninitialized and MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD not set  
   Did you forget to add -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=... ?
```

Since I now set the variable `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD`

```
$ docker-compose up

Attaching to myapp_db_1, myapp_web_1
db_1  | Running mysql_install_db
db_1  | ...
```

I can see the whole db log and the `db` host effectively set in `web`'s `/etc/hosts`